# Expand environment variables in Qt (getenv equivalent)

Tags: c++, qt, environment-variables

I'm looking for an equivalent of the [getenv](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/getenv/) function.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Qt has a wrapper around `getenv()`, called [`qgetenv()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qgetenv).

```
QByteArray qgetenv ( const char * varName )
```

`getenv()` is a standard function, but Visual Studio has deprecated it which is why Qt provides the `qgetenv()` wrapper.

Note that if you're interested in getting standard filesystem locations (like the home directory, application data directory, etc.) you should instead use [`QDesktopServices::storageLocation()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdesktopservices.html#storageLocation) (Qt 4) or [`QStandardPaths::writableLocation()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qstandardpaths.html#writableLocation) (Qt 5).

Comment: Is this a function that expands any environment variable, like %PATH%, etc.? For example, a custom environment variable that I set from the command line before invoking my process?

Comment: @satuon No. It gets you standard locations like the home directory of the user and the application data directory. And others. Custom environment variables will of course need to be fetched with getenv(). Qt doesn't abstract getenv(), since it's a standard function available on all standard C++ compilers.

Comment: Actually, there's qgetenv: http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qtglobal.html#qgetenv Because: "qgetenv() was introduced because getenv() from the standard C library was deprecated in VC2005 (and later versions). qgetenv() uses the new replacement function in VC, and calls the standard C library's implementation on all other platforms."

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld Good catch. Something I didn't know.

Comment: In what sense? It answers my question, which was: how do I expand an environment variable in general, and is there an equivalent to getenv in Qt. I was merely giving made up examples with %APPDATA% and $HOME, I did not need them specifically. I've edited my question to remove any mention of them, now I hope it's more clear.

Comment: @satuon I edited it now to make more sense. Previously it looked like the answer suggested using getenv() to get standard filesystem locations.

Comment: Can someone please share a working code snippet of this where it's stored in a variable? Because the accepted answer does bupkis with the information provided.

Comment: Alright, finally got it working. Here's an example: `QByteArray derp;`
    `derp = qgetenv ("OS");`

Answer (score 13):

For Qt, there is also a "high-level" approach when accessing environment variables. This only works, if your Qt application runs within a QCoreApplication, which should be the case for most Qt applications.

In that case, you can use [QProcessEnvironment](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocessenvironment.html), for Qt versions of at least 4.6. You can access the current process environment by using

```
QProcessEnvironment::systemEnvironment();
```

and you can query any variable via

```
QProcessEnvironment::systemEnvironment().value("<variablename>", "<defaultvalue>");
```

This should be more convenient that using the getenv/qgetenv approach in most cases as this shadows the operating-system implementation in a more generic way and IMHO it is also a more "Qt-alike" approach.

Comment: Also, unlike `getenv` it supports correctly environment variables containing Unicode characters.

Comment: `QProcessEnvironment` is meant to be used along with **QProcess**, to set the environment for child processes. **It cannot be used to change the current process's environment** , see documentation [ QProcessEnvironment](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocessenvironment.html#details)