# QFile path changing from build version to deploy version

Tags: qt, save, qfile

I have a program that saves data inside it's own folder. This is how I save the data:

```
QString path = "./config/Values/"+Name+"/";
QDir *myDir = new QDir();
myDir->mkpath(path);
path += Name+"_";
path += Date+".txt";
QFile File(path);
QTextStream Out(&File);
Out.setCodec("UTF-8");
if(!File.open(QFile::WriteOnly | QFile::Text))
   return;
out << data;
File.close();
```

Every time I run the program through QT, the saved data goes to the path: `C:\Andre\Qt files\build-Pesquisa-Desktop_Qt_5_7_0_MinGW_32bit-Release\release\config\Values`. I will send the full path for clarity sake.

However, I made an installer for that program. The program is installed in `C:\Program Files (x86)\SOCC_Pesquisa`. So the new path should be: `C:\Program Files (x86)\SOCC_Pesquisa\config\Values` right?

Although, when I run the program and check where the data was saved, I get this path: `C:\Users\SOCC\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files (x86)\SOCC_Pesquisa\config\Values`. Why does it change suddently to such a different folder?

EDIT: Via making a few tests I found out the problem is not in the installer, but in the place where it is installed. For some reason when I pass my program to `C:\Program Files (x86)`, the data is always saved in `C:\Users\SOCC\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files (x86)\SOCC_Pesquisa\config\Values`. is it because of the user? or maybe admin rights?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to security features introduced with Windows Vista (UAC) any non-Administrator program that tries to write to protected locations such as "Program Files" will get their writes caught and redirected to an alternative "user friendly" location.

In you case `C:\Users\SOCC\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files (x86)\SOCC_Pesquisa\config\Values`

You can find out more about UAC [here on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control)

So you can move in these directions:

1. Run program as administrator each time.
2. Change directory's security settings: going properties, select the Security tab and then advanced.
3. Request elevation for your app as you can find on [Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control#Requesting_elevation).
4. Change the savings location to a more secure and usual, like documents or whatever you want not conflicting with UAC

Comment: In what folders does the UAC act?

Comment: I don't really remember, but you can see it in the folder permissions. You can check if the folder you want to write to is UAC protected.

Comment: Thank you very much. Not only you told me what was the problem but also helped me go in the right direction :)

Comment: Use LOCALAPPDATA environment variable for finding where the application data should go. In cmd `dir %LOCALAPPDATA%`. Also you can make installer and the app code to explicitly use that location at all times and that will be correct unless you want use the other location.

Comment: @AlexanderVX But if I give the absolute path, wouldn't it change from computer to computer? What is the "correct way" I should pass a path?

Comment: @andseg http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14200420/expand-environment-variables-in-qt-getenv-equivalent I do %LOCALAPPDATA% + MyAppName